# вызов хранимой процедуры в программе Code First

Tags: c#, база-данных, entity-framework

Создал простенькую процедуру в БД MS SQL Server

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[SumPages] @summ int output
as
select @summ = sum(Pages) from Books
```

пытаюсь вызвать ее в программе

```
public void func()
        {
            using (db = new BookContext())
            {
                var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.SumPages";
                try
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Open();
                    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    var books = ((IObjectContextAdapter)db).ObjectContext.Translate<Book>(reader, "Books", MergeOption.AppendOnly);
                    MessageBox.Show(books.ToString());
                }
                catch
                {
                    db.Database.Connection.Close();
                }

            }
        }
```

делаю видимо не правильно, так как ничего не выводит. Пробовал и через SqlParametr
Подскажите в чем ошибка

вылетает такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо "глушить" ошибки пустым `catch`. Надо `catch(Exception ex)` и выводить хотя бы так `Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)`, в случае ошибки можно хотя бы понять из сообщения в чем причина. `db.Database.Connection.Close();` должно быть в  блоке `finally`, а не там где у вас.

Comment: @Bulson исправил, теперь вылетает такая ошибка (правил в вопросе)

Comment: Теперь по-моему все стало очевидно. Нужно передать параметр в запросе.

Comment: @Bulson cmd.CommandText = "exec dbo.SumPages @summ"; если так правильно, тоже не работает

Comment: Уберите `exec ` и укажите CommandType = StoredProcedure

Comment: @4per и что оно даст?

Comment: Скорей всего ничего, но так правильней будет (:

Comment: А так вам ещё нужно добавить ваш параметр summ в cmd.Parameters, вызвать команду через `ExecuteNonQuery()` и потом прочитать значение в параметре.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т. к. вы указали параметр в запросе, то нужно его использовать. Добавляем его к команде, указываем тип `Output`. После выполнения запроса получаем результат из параметра.

```
using (var db = new BookContext())
using (var cmd = db.Database.Connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "dbo.SumPages";

    var param = new SqlParameter("summ", SqlDbType.Int);
    param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param);

    db.Database.Connection.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Console.WriteLine(param.Value);
}
```

Comment: спасибо, понял в чем ошибки были